# How Does CMTimeCompare Work?

Tags: ios, cmtime

How does CMTimeCompare work? Apple seems to have left out the return values from their documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html

I assume if the times are equal it returns zero and return positive or negative 1 based on which is greater?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From **CMTime.h**:

> Returns the numerical relationship (-1 = less than, 1 = greater than,
>   0 = equal) of two CMTimes.
>
> -1 is returned if time1 is less than time2. 0 is returned if they are equal. 1 is returned if time1 is greater than time2.

**EDIT:**

Please note that:

> Invalid CMTimes are considered to be equal to other invalid CMTimes,
>   and greater than
>       any other CMTime. Positive infinity is considered to be less than any invalid CMTime,
>       equal to itself, and greater than any other CMTime. An indefinite CMTime is considered
>       to be less than any invalid CMTime, less than positive infinity, equal to itself,
>       and greater than any other CMTime.  Negative infinity is considered to be equal to itself,
>       and less than any other CMTime.

Comment: If I do `CMTimeCompare(a, b)` it returns -1 if a < b?

Answer (score 4):

For an alternative that's much easier to read than `CMTimeCompare()`, consider using the `CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE` [macro](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/index.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE). For example

```
CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(time1, <=, time2)
```

will return true if time1 <= time2

Comment: Unfortunately, CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE is not (yet) available in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Here is it in `Swift 5` with a very easy explanation using `AVPlayerItem` and its `.currentTime()` and `.duration`

```
let videoCurrentTime = playerItem.currentTime() // eg. the video is at the 30 sec point
let videoTotalDuration = playerItem.duration // eg. the video is 60 secs long in total

// 1. this will be false because if the videoCurrentTime is at 30 and it's being compared to the videoTotalDuration which is 60 then they are not equal.
if CMTimeCompare(videoCurrentTime, videoTotalDuration) == 0 { // 0 means equal

    print("do something")
    // the print statement will NOT run because this is NOT true
    // it is the same thing as saying: if videoCurrentTime == videoCurrentTime { do something }
}

// 2. this will be true because if the videoCurrentTime is at 30 and it's being compared to the videoTotalDuration which is 60 then they are not equal.
if CMTimeCompare(videoCurrentTime, videoTotalDuration) != 0 { // != 0 means not equal

    print("do something")
    // the print statement WILL run because it IS true
    // this is the same thing as saying: if videoCurrentTime != videoTotalDuration { do something }
}

// 3. this will be true because if the videoCurrentTime is at 30 and it's being compared to 0 then 30 is greater then 0
if CMTimeCompare(videoCurrentTime, .zero) == 1 { // 1 means greater than

    print("do something")
    // the print statement WILL run because it IS true
    // this is the same thing as saying: if videoCurrentTime > 0 { do something }
}

// 4. this will be true because if the videoCurrentTime is at 30 and it's being compared to the videoTotalDuration which is 60 then 30 is less than 60
if CMTimeCompare(videoCurrentTime, videoTotalDuration) == -1 { // -1 means less than

    print("do something")
    // the print statement WILL run because it IS true
    // this is the same thing as saying: if videoCurrentTime < videoTotalDuration { do something }
}
```